# Is it possible to add code files to project folder immediately

Tags: visual-studio, import

I work on Visual Studio 2013.
Normally we just `new project`, then `add` some head files and some source files to build our projects.
Now I have a question:
Is it possible to add code files to project folder?
For example, I created a project and added some head and source files. Now I want to add an existing file into this project. For now, what I can do is right click on my project in Visual Studio and select `add` to add a file and copy the content of that existing file in the file which I just added.
I am considering if I could just move the existing file into my project folder and Visual Studio can compile it with my project immediately, this must be a very good thing.

Btw, what I am talking about is NOT about lib files, it's about the code files. For example, in my project there have been `a.h`, `a.cpp`, `b.h`, `b.cpp`. Now I have a file `x.cpp` which comes from my USB and I want to move `x.cpp` into my project and compile it with my project. I think it's about "import" or something like this.

Comment: Just add the file to the proejct using the "add file" option.

Comment: @Ramhound  How? I didnt find "add file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the solution of your project in the Visual
   Studio.
2. Select `add` then `add existing item`.

Now the existing file has been added in your project.